# Multiple values for IFS in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am coding a shell program which needs to have multiple internal field separator values - `<newline><tab><.><space>`. Is there any way to assign all these to IFS? Also I am not talking about awk here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash you can re-assign those multiple values like this:

```
IFS=$'\n\t. '
```

In other shells you have to do it manually or use other external commands to generate it:

```
IFS="
    . "
```